# Concise highlighting function when divs are clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Conundrum for today:**

I'm trying to create a function where the divs underneath the image `highlight1A, highlight1B` gain a class `.highlight` when the corresponding divs over the image `choice1A, choice1B` are clicked. So what should happen is when `choice1A` is clicked, `highlight1A` is highlighted. Like so:

[image]

But the thing that happens is, when I click one `choice`, it highlights both divs behind the image.

[image]

I'm trying to get the most concise function for this exercise because I'm also going to apply it to exercises where there will be more `choice` divs and more `highlight` divs. I'd like to use this so I don't have to do much editing on the `.js` file. I want to be able to focus on editing the `HTML` so all I have to do is add / subtract divs from the source file according to how many divs are needed for the following exercises.

**Javascript:**

```
function choice1 () {
        if ($('div[id^="highlight1"]').hasClass('highlight')) {
            $('div[id^="highlight1"]').removeClass('highlight');
        } else {
            $('div[id^="highlight1"]').addClass('highlight');
        }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="choice1A" class="click1A"></div>
<div id="choice1B" class="click1B"></div>
<img src="../../../../images/chapter_5/CH5L4_21.png" width="276" height="147"/>
<div id="highlight1A" class="click1A"></div>
<div id="highlight1B" class="click1B"></div>
```

Also, if you generous coders would care to offer a few explanations for the codes you provide, it would be much appreciated, as I'm also looking to expand my knowledge of JavaScript and jQuery.

Thank you so much!

Comment: you could use `toggleClass` method. http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: how is `choice1` called

Comment: if you were a good HTML related question asker, you would offered some [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so that the answers would feel much easier to dig into your problem and of course they would give the answers more quickly.

Comment: the problem is `$('div[id^="highlight1"]').addClass('highlight');` which adds teh class `highlight` to all elements with id starting like  `highlight1` instead of targeting only `highlight1A` or `highlight1B` - to know which one has to be highlighted we need to know which choice was clicked.. which is missing here

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a reason why you are approaching the problem this way, if there is, please comment and I will edit my answer.

But the simplest way to solve this problem is actually really undemanding. [Here is a demo I coded for you](http://jsbin.com/qirev/1/).

What you need to do is:

1. Have a container element around your image;
2. Bind a `click` event on the container element, and use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

And that's it. The event handler will work even while clicking the image instead of the container due to [**Event bubbling**](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).

### HTML

Your HTML could look like this:

```
<div class="container"><img src="http://www.example.com/image.png"></div>
<div class="container"><img src="http://www.example.com/image.png"></div>
```

### CSS

```
div.container {
  background-color: #fff;
}

div.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

### JS

```
$('.container').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```